# Does the number of columns used for a CTE affects the performance of the query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, common-table-expression

Using more columns within a CTE query affects the performance? I am currently trying to execute a query with the WITH sentence, and it seams that if I use more colum,s, it takes more time to load the data. Am I correct?

Comment: It depends. More columns -> probably reading data that is not in index -> slower execution.

Comment: SQL Server does column-optimization on subqueries (including CTEs) so it shouldn't matter, it will only returns the columns that you actually use.

Answer (score 3):

The number of columns defined in a CTE should have no effect on the actual performance of the query (it might affect the compile-time, which is generally miniscule).

Why?  Because SQL Server "embeds" the code for the CTE in the query itself and then optimizes all the code together.  Unused columns should be eliminated.

This might be an over generalization.  There might be some cases where SQL Server doesn't eliminate the work for columns -- such as extra aggregation functions in an aggregation query or certain subqueries.  But, in general, what is important is how the CTE is used, not how many columns are defined in it.

Comment: Is that serious? Are you saying if we pull 2-3 columns, or 100 columns the performance will be the same? This doesn't sound realistic to me.

Comment: @peter.petrov: You have mis-interpreted; the optimizer will attempt to recognize, based on the top-level SELECT list, all columns in subqueries that are not ever used in the output, and optimize out all references to them and their effect on index selection, etc. Think of it as a variation on GC. However the optimizer is required to complete its analysis in a small finite time, and thus this process cannot be relied upon in arbitrarily complex queries. In cases where such optimization must be aborted before completion, use of covering indices (for example) may not be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of CTE as  a View but it doesnt materialize to Disk.So A view expands it definition at run time ,same goes for CTE.